# Cannot set font-family to AvantGard in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts

I want to add AvantGard font to one paragraph in my React app, but it seems the font has no effect and I don't know why, here is how I am adding it:

1. I keep it as a ttf file in my assets folder.
2. I have global scss file index.css and I declare it there like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AvantGard';
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('./assets/fonts/avant_gartt/AvantGard.ttf');
}
```

3. I also have a variables.scss in which I keep it like this:

```
$avantGard: 'AvantGuard';
```

4. I import my variables in my component's css like this:

```
@import './variables.scss';
```

and then I just set the font-size of my paragraph:

```
 font-family: $avantGard;
```

Does anyone have any idea why my font does not work? The rest of my fonts work the same way, but not this one.

Comment: Is the path to the font file correct from the context of your index.css file? It may help to show your file structure in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Check your spelling on number 3.
AvantGard or AvantGuard?